# How can I make grid input boxes nxn in a div using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make N input boxes placed to create an NxN input area square. I tried it using `<br>` after each N square placed. But this was not resulted as I want. Because there are spaces between squares and that's something I don't want. Also using `<br>` isn't a good way to do this, I think. Is there another way to make this thing succesfully?

**My codes to create a 3x3 square:**

```css
 .box {
   margin-right: 0px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <br>
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <br>
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `width` on `div` and remove `white-space`'s

```css
div {
  width: 90px;
}
.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text"><input class="box" type="text">
</div>
```

You can also use `Flexbox`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90px;
}
.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
  <input class="box" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't work for me. So I can't get the result as same above. I can't understand why. Am I missing something? My result http://uploads.im/cO3Pm.png

Comment: You need to remove `white-space` from `HTML`. Copy paste my html and try again.

Comment: Ok. It is done. I was wrong about the white space. But the line takes so much place in IDE. Is this always done like this?

Comment: You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements